# R: check if a vector is part of any row in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

Suppose I have this vector `c("a", "b", "c")` and the following data frame:

```
a d t g h
r a b c
a b c
m p o a b t
c t b a
a b c t g
```

My vector will always be of length 3, and each data frame row can have a length between 3 and 6 columns. How can I check that my vector is part of a data.frame row, without looping through each element of each row?

For the example I gave, the expected output would be:

```
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
```

Comment: Does order matter? It would be helpful if you would share your sample data with `dput()` so we can see the structure...

Comment: @Gregor Yeah, the order matters. That is why the second to last row (`c t b a`) was flagged as `FALSE`.

Comment: What's in the "empty" entries - `NA`, `""`, something else?  It would be helpful if you would share your sample data with `dput()` so we can see the structure. Just type `dput(head(your_data))` and paste the result in the question.

Comment: @Gregor, the empty entries could be either, NA or "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An one liner solution can be written using `apply` and `stringr::detect` as

```
library(stringr)

apply(df, 1, function(x)str_detect(paste(x, collapse=""), paste(v, collapse="")))

#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

**Note:** One can use `grepl` instead of `str_detect`.

Comment: I couldn't make it work with grepl, but with str_detect works perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

Just create a single string with each row then use `grepl`.

```
# My version of your data
check_values <- c("a", "b", "c")
my_data <- structure(list(V1 = c("a", "r", "a", "m", "c", "a"), V2 = c("d", 
"a", "b", "p", "t", "b"), V3 = c("t", "b", "c", "o", "b", "c"
), V4 = c("g", "c", NA, "a", "a", "t"), V5 = c("h", NA, NA, "b", 
NA, "g"), V6 = c(NA, NA, NA, "t", NA, NA)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

# Actual solution
row_strings <- do.call(paste0, my_data)
check_string <- paste0(check_values, collapse = "")
grepl(check_string, row_strings, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I remember [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun?tab=answers) posted an answer which was really helpful towards my problem. I tried to find the original answer but had no luck; here is the approach in reference to his answer:

```
do.call(paste0, df) %in% 
                 do.call(paste0, df[apply(df, 1, function(x) all(diff(match(vec, x))>0)),])

#  [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```